# OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud won't autosize

Tags: openlayers-2

I don't see why this shouldn't work, but it doesn't.. :P

> var popuphtml="";
>       $.each(persons.persons,function(i,item){
>       if(item.in_loc == feature.attributes['locid'].substring(8)){
>                                       popuphtml +=""+
>                 ""
>                   + item.lastName  +" " + item.firstName + "
> ";
>                    }
>                 });
>
> ```
>           popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("chicken", 
>           feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
>           null,
>           popuphtml,                            
>           null,
>           true,
>           onPopupClose);
>           popup.autoSize = true;
>           panMapIfOutOfView=true;
>           feature.popup = popup;
>           map.addPopup(popup);
> ```